# Extracting Strings from JSON Object - REST Assured

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I have a JSON response from an API in the following form:

```
{
    "Sample String 1"
    "Sample String 2"
}
```

I can get the response in the Response object with

```
String response = get("/url").asString();
```

and I get back the response as

```
{
    String1,
    String2
}
```

Is there any way to just extract the valid strings using any REST Assured methods i.e. String1 and String2 into a collection without the accompanying braces? The documentation mentions that values can be extracted by using the names of nodes but in this case the JSON response is just a collection of strings.

Comment: Your sample response is not JSON.  Objects are key/value pairs and your sample has no value, e.g. `{"a":1}`.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JSON.  But if you really want to turn that into a String array, you can do this:

```
String str = "{ String1, String2 }"
String[] arr = str
    .replace('{','') // Get rid of left brackets
    .replace('}','') // Get rid of right brackets
    .replace(' ','') // Get rid of spaces
    .split(',');     // Split on commas
```

Which should give you an array like ["String1", "String2"]

Note that the code above is not the most robust or efficient way to do it (not even close).  You should really try to get a valid JSON response and use a known parser like JackSON or GSON.  But if you really just want to parse it as-is, that should work.

Comment: Don't forget quotation marks, and don't forget to escape quotation marks in the target strings...

Comment: Like I was saying, my answer is basically only good if we have consistently nice input (no commas in values, no spaces, no quotes, etc).  JSON Parser is clearly the way to go otherwise you'll get a regex mess.